# Which is the proper way to convert html text to attributed text for a UILabel inside UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I need to convert html text to attributed string. The following code working fine, but I'm updating a label which is in a `UITableViewCell`. Thus below code taking good time to convert to an  "attributed string".

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] 
initWithData:[[stPhoto photoDetails] dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] 
options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

myLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

I have tried running following code inside a `dispatch_async` block, but that doesn't help.

Any other way?

I have tried to use `DTCoreText` lib but its installation process is a way complicated and I shouldn't go with `DTCoreText` framework for such a small task.

Any other ways?

My HTML text may contains following:
Bold + Italic + Underlin + Bullets + Text Color

Please suggest me something !! It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are two simple options for you

1. Use asynch converting from html to NSAttributedString. Not sure what you mean when talking that it doesn't help. This procedure faster then showing images which works good enough when asynch preloading used.
2. Preprocess data and store photoDetails as NSAttributedString instead of regular NSString with html content.

Comment: 2nd option is sounds good! :) I'll apply and let you know here.

Comment: I believe you are not supposed to use option #1 because the (very complex! hence slow...) NSAttributedString code that does the conversion is not thread-safe. It usually works, but...